# how to add multiple rows in a container widget?

Tags: flutter

I would like to add some `Row`s in a container widget, here is what i tried to do.
The `Row`s does not appear in Vertical position but instead they appear  in Horizontal position.

```
 Container(
  height: 50,
 color:Color(0xFFFFFF),

  child: Row(children: <Widget>[
    Row(children:<Widget>[
  Text('L\'intelligent d\'Abidjan en ligne')]),
  Row(children:<Widget>[Text('le journal en ligne dont vous avez rêvé', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 
  20))]),
  Row(children:<Widget>[RaisedButton(onPressed: (){},
   shape: roundedRectangleBorder,
       child: Text('cliquez pour vous abonner', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
        color: Color(0xFF1705),
    )]),
     Row(children:<Widget>[Text('le journal en ligne dont vous avez rêvé', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 
   20)) ])

  ]),


  ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to keep the top widget as `Column` and wrap all of your `Rows` as children for it..

Like this..

```
Container(
child: Row(
  children: <widget>[
    Row(), //your 1st Row
    Row(), //your 2nd Row
    Row(), //your 3rd Row
  ],
),
)
```

Specifically, in your case..I believe, you should do like this..

```
Container(
  height: 50,
 color:Color(0xFFFFFF),

  child: Column( //you kept this as Row
    children: <Widget>[
    Row(children:<Widget>[
  Text('L\'intelligent d\'Abidjan en ligne')]),
  Row(children:<Widget>[Text('le journal en ligne dont vous avez rêvé', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 
  20))]),
  Row(children:<Widget>[RaisedButton(onPressed: (){},
   shape: roundedRectangleBorder,
       child: Text('cliquez pour vous abonner', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
        color: Color(0xFF1705),
    )]),
     Row(children:<Widget>[Text('le journal en ligne dont vous avez rêvé', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 
   20)) ])

  ]),
```

Hope it answers your question..

Comment: it works very well, now if i want to introduce a seperator between the ist elements, what can i do?

Comment: and what if i want to center a row?

Comment: To center the `Row` items.. ```Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: <widget>[])```